# Postgres - Search rows of table A based on strings from table B

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two tables, one (table A) with products inside (name, price, etc) and another table with just strings (a table with one column "keywords").

How would I construct a query which fetches me all the products from table A "productName" that contains any string from table B's "keywords" column?

table A:

```
| productId      | productName | Price
| -------------  | ----------- | -------
| 0              | Red Shoe    | 100
| 1              | Yellow Boot | 20
| 2              | Scarf       | 30
| 3              | Cardigan    | 40
```

table B:

```
| Keywords      |
| ------------- |
| Scarf     |
| Shoe      |
| Red |
```

I would get the red shoe and scarf as my result

Comment: Please add a sample of your keyword table.

Comment: Apologies. Was trying to figure out if there was a markdown table for stackoverflow @McNets

Comment: I use this: http://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables

Comment: And this fiddle: dbfiddle.uk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> create table product(productId int, productName text, Price int);
> insert into product values
> (0, 'Red Shoe', 100),
> (1, 'Yellow Boot', 20),
> (2, 'Scarf', 30),
> (3, 'Cardigan', 40);
>
> create table keywords(kwords text);
> insert into keywords values
> ( 'Scarf'),('Shoe'),('Red');
> ```

Let me suggest to have a look at [Postgres Full Text Search](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/textsearch-intro.html#TEXTSEARCH-DOCUMENT).

> ```
> select *
> from   product
>        ,lateral (select kwords from keywords) k
> where productName like '%' || kwords || '%'
> ```
>
> ```
> productid | productname | price | kwords
> --------: | :---------- | ----: | :-----
>         2 | Scarf       |    30 | Scarf 
>         0 | Red Shoe    |   100 | Shoe  
>         0 | Red Shoe    |   100 | Red
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=dc9006df2ddbe9d92a078a0ee6030692)*

Answer (score 1):

I would approach this as:

```
select p.*
from product p
where exists (select 1
              from keywords k
              where p.productName like '%' || k.keyword || '%'
             );
```

This is potentially dangerous, if keywords can be contained in each other.  For instance, "shoelace" would always match "shoe".